# Parsing SOAP objects

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm trying to `Deserialize` a SOAP message back into an instance of a custom `class` and am having some formatting issues.  The `class` is defined in a c# file that was generated from `SvcUtil.exe`.

Messages that I receive from the service are formatted in the following fashion, but when I try to serialize my own from an instance of the same class, they look different...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:sde1="http://www.somedomain.com/xml/SomeName/" 
xmlns:sde2="http://www.somedomain.com/xml/2013/05/17/SomeName.xsd">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <sde2:notification_message>
        <sde2:startup_notification 
        xml_version="http://www.somedomain.com/xml/2013/05/17/SomeName.xsd" 
        reboot_type="SOAP_REBOOT_POWERON" 
        customer_version="unsupported feature" 
        firmware_version="2.2.2.2" 
        ip_address="192.168.1.11" 
        osd_state="OSD_STATE_OK" 
        timestamp="1970-01-01T00:09:00.048895+00:00" 
        callerType_ID="SELF" 
        serverTask_ID="0" 
        notification_ID="19" 
        task_type="TASK_STARTUP" 
        customer_ID="SOMENAME0129" 
        mac_address="00:00:00:00:00:00">
        </sde2:startup_notification>
    </sde2:notification_message>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My own attempt...

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" 
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:StartupNotification id="ref-1" 
    xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/assem/MSGReceive%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
    <reboot_typeField>SOAP_REBOOT_POWERON</reboot_typeField>
    <xml_versionField id="ref-3">http://www.somedomain.com/xml/2013/05/17/SomeName.xsd</xml_versionField>
    <ExtendedNotificationBase_x002B_ip_addressField id="ref-4">192.168.1.11</ExtendedNotificationBase_x002B_ip_addressField>
    <ExtendedNotificationBase_x002B_firmware_versionField id="ref-5">2.2.2.2</ExtendedNotificationBase_x002B_firmware_versionField>
    <ExtendedNotificationBase_x002B_customer_versionField id="ref-6">unsupported feature</ExtendedNotificationBase_x002B_customer_versionField>
    <NotificationWithOSDState_x002B_osd_stateField>OSD_STATE_OK</NotificationWithOSDState_x002B_osd_stateField>
    <NotificationBase_x002B_mac_addressField id="ref-7">00:00:00:00:00:00</NotificationBase_x002B_mac_addressField>
    <NotificationBase_x002B_customer_IDField id="ref-8">SOMENAME0129</NotificationBase_x002B_customer_IDField>
    <NotificationBase_x002B_task_typeField>TASK_STARTUP</NotificationBase_x002B_task_typeField>
    <NotificationBase_x002B_notification_IDField>19</NotificationBase_x002B_notification_IDField>
    <NotificationBase_x002B_serverTask_IDField>0</NotificationBase_x002B_serverTask_IDField>
    <NotificationBase_x002B_callerType_IDField id="ref-9">SELF</NotificationBase_x002B_callerType_IDField>
    <NotificationBase_x002B_timestampField>2016-10-27T14:03:03.7532987-04:00</NotificationBase_x002B_timestampField>
</a1:StartupNotification>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here's the code I'm using to create an instance of the class I'd like to be able to Serialize/Deserialize.  Right now I'm just attempting to serialize my own and visually compare the results to what I'm receiving from the service.

```
StartupNotification sn = new StartupNotification();

sn.xml_version = "http://www.somedomain.com/xml/2013/05/17/SomeName.xsd";
sn.reboot_type = RebootType.SOAP_REBOOT_POWERON;
sn.customer_version = "unsupported feature";
sn.firmware_version = "2.2.2.2";
sn.ip_address = "192.168.1.11";
sn.osd_state = OSD_State.OSD_STATE_OK;
sn.timestamp = DateTime.Now;
sn.callerType_ID = "SELF";
sn.serverTask_ID = 0;
sn.notification_ID = 19;
sn.task_type = TaskType.TASK_STARTUP;
sn.customer_ID = "SOMENAME0129";
sn.mac_address = "00:00:00:00:00:00";

NotificationContainer nc = new NotificationContainer();
nc.Item = sn;

SoapFormatter sf = new SoapFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

sf.Serialize(ms, nc);

string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer());
return output;
```

It would be very helpful if someone could potentially help me diagnose some reasons why my serialized object looks different from the output from a service that is using the same classes.  I'm just looking for some leads to look into or if I'm overlooking something simple.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Added requested information on StartupNotificiation.  This class inherits from like 3 other layers up but they're all formatted the same way, just adding new properties.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.somedomain.com/xml/2013/05/17/SomeName.xsd")]
public partial class StartupNotification : ExtendedNotificationBase {

    private RebootType reboot_typeField;

    private string xml_versionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public RebootType reboot_type {
        get {
            return this.reboot_typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.reboot_typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string xml_version {
        get {
            return this.xml_versionField;
        }
        set {
            this.xml_versionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by getting namespace correct in root.  You have clr instead of sde1  and sde2.

Comment: Can you add the generated code for the StartupNotification class? It looks like the underlying fields are serialized in place of the properties.

Comment: @WvanNoort I've added the requested information.  When I serialize with the XmlSerializer, it does the properties correctly, but using the SoapFormatter, they are done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SoapFormatter is intended to support RPC calls in remoting scenarios where both ends of the channel use .NET. It will add some metadata about the assembly and the types to the output.

If you want to create a SOAP message manually, you can better use the XmlSerializer and wrap your class in a typemapper like descibed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5wt2he6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Edit:
Forget the typemapper, it does not work as the description suggests. One way i know for sure will work is to add the soap envelope using a little manual coding:

```
XElement snElement;
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StartupNotification));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     mySerializer.Serialize(ms, sn);
     ms.Position = 0;
     snElement = XElement.Load(ms);
}

XNamespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XElement soap = new XElement(soapenv + "Envelope",
new XElement(soapenv + "Body", snElement));
// use soap.ToString() to inspect the result
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the typemapping thing.  Will this allow me to wrap my XML serialized object in a soap envelope?  Do I need to add SOAP specific attributes manually or can I regenerate the class created from SvcUtil with different attributes... I'm a bit lost.